# systemd-modules-load failed to find module for soundcard

Tags: systemd, pulseaudio, alsa, intel, module

My soundcard won't reproduce any sound nor receive it.

I was looking at the journalctl and this popped out:

```
Mar 07 20:14:16 debian systemd-modules-load[204]: Inserted module 'snd_hda_intel'
Mar 07 20:14:16 debian systemd-modules-load[204]: Inserted module 'snd_intel8x0'
Mar 07 20:14:16 debian systemd-modules-load[204]: Failed to find module 'snd-intel8x0in'
```

it pops out ~100 times.

The system is debian 10 (buster) with kernel 5.0.3

I have no idea how to solve this (i have the libraries that include the module but i have no idea how to make systemd detect it)

Comment: What do you have in `/etc/modules-load.d/*.conf`? What output do you get from `modinfo snd-intel8x0in`?

Comment: cat of *.conf https://pastebin.com/CcqSjeXD


modinfo: ERROR: Module snd-intel8x0in not found.

Comment: `ERROR: Module snd-intel8x0in not found` explains why you get the error when trying to load this module. It doesn't exist. A quick google for *snd-intel8x0in* brought a single result, which was a typo. Now, what modules are required for your sound card, I can't say.

Comment: yup i've seen it... so i am basically screwed. Is there a way to find the author of the driver itself?

Comment: The snd-intel8x0 driver should be developed by the [ALSA project](http://www.alsa-project.org/).